# UML class diagram: how to annotate observer-subject relationship?

Tags: object-oriented, uml, observer-pattern

How can I annotate in a UML class diagram that an instance of ClassA is registered as an observer of an instance of ClassB? (Both implement the appropriate interfaces).

This doesn't really belong in a class diagram, because they are static, but if this is something that is important to the design - how can you annotate it in this type of diagram?

Edit:

To clarify: I know how to annotate the Observer pattern in UML. My question is more specific.

ClassA being registered as an observer to ClassB is important for the design, however I'm not sure if an association relationship between the two classes is appropriate, since **ClassA and ClassB don't know about each other. They're totally decoupled, and only connected through the Observer pattern**.

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense. If A is registered as an Observer to B, an instance of A is passed into the registerObserver() method of B. B may not know about the A's interface, but it must be aware of some object that implements the Observer interface. It's not usually necessary, but could you post some sample code? Show a stub of ClassA and ClassB with the interfaces and abstract classes they inherit from and the method signatures?

Answer (score 1):

Documenting this type of relationship is suitable for a class diagram. You can add role names to the association links between classes, similar to how it's demonstrated on Scott Ambler's [introduction to UML class diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm) or [the Wikipedia example of Associations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Association). I would also indicate the fact that they implement the interfaces or inherit from the base class, even if you are using a language like Java that provides the necessary classes (although I would consider omitting the details for these language-provided classes).

You can also apply notes in the UML diagram. Most tools that I've used allow for attaching notes to classes. These could annotate the usage of a pattern or even provide for a pseudocode implementation of a few functions, if it doesn't lead to clutter on the diagram.

Comment: An association relationship usually means that a class holds a reference to another, or 'knows about it' in some other way. With Observer, the observer and the subject are decoupled meaning they don't know about each other. So is it suitable to draw an association arrow from the observer to the subject, even though the observer doesn't actually know about the subject? (Which is part of the point of this pattern).

Comment: @Prog Association is the generic form of aggregation and composition. Your subject typically maintains a collection of observers, and that's usually represented with aggregation. Since it's a form of association, you can annotate it in the same way.

Comment: Not sure if I explained myself correctly, I'll explain again what I mean: ClassA implements the Observer interface, ClassB the Subject interface (and it's annotated in the diagram). ClassA is registered as an observer to ClassB (which is an integral part of the design). Drawing an association arrow from ClassA to ClassB, or from ClassB to ClassA, I think would imply that *ClassA 'knows about' ClassB, or vice versa - which is wrong.* They are totally decoupled from each other. But it **is** important in order to understand the design, to see that ClassA is an observer of ClassB.

Comment: So can I draw this arrow from A to B, even though A *doesn't actually 'know about'* B?

Comment: @Prog A may not know B, but B must least know about the Observer interface and maintain some kind of collection of them to notify when an update happens. You should check out the [class diagram for the Observer pattern on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). That is very similar to how it's presented in the GoF book as well.

Comment: I know that B would be annotatetd with an aggregation connection to the Observer interface. But what I'm asking is if Class A can be connected to *A itself - not the Subject interface* - if this specific relationship is important to the design (the relationship specifically between A and B, and not the fact that A has a collection of Observers, which is more general)

Comment: If there is a relationship between A and B that is relevant to the information you are trying to present, yes, put it on the class diagram. I honestly don't get what your problem is anymore. I've explained how to annotate the relationships. Either the relationship is important and it goes on the class diagram with appropriate annotations or it isn't and it doesn't.

Comment: @Prog:UML does not cover every situation that you want to document in a way that you want to document it. It is a very rare project where people aren't "inventing" their own ways of using UML to communicate what they mean. YES, that is what UML was supposed to resolve but UML took a turn away from being a communication tool to being more CASE Tool designer friendly many years ago. That means that people in the real world have to either use "Notes" in the diagrams or hijack existing features for their own meaning. If it is important to understanding then show it in an adhoc way that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

UML defines a special diagram type for showing how class instances are connected to each other: [the Object diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram).

An object diagram uses a similar notation to a class diagram, but rather than structural relations between types, it shows how objects are relating to each other at some point in time.

In your concrete case, you would have two diagrams:

- A class diagram showing how `ClassA` is an `Observer` and `ClassB` a `Subject` in the Observer Pattern, and
- an object diagram showing the relevant instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` with a dependency between them (dashed arrow with open arrow head) with the stereotype `<<observes>>`. This diagram then shows that a particular instance of `ClassA` at some point in time is connected to a particular instance of `ClassB` through the observer pattern.